# Change the colour of a tkinter button generated in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

In python tkinter, I've got a program that generates multiple buttons with a default `fg` of red

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def dothis(i):
    print(i)
    button.config(fg='green')

for i in range(5):
    button = Button(root, width=30, text="button{}".format(i), command=lambda i=i: dothis(i))
    button.config(fg='red')
    button.pack()
```

This creates this window:

[image]

In this program, I have attempted to make it so that once the button is pressed, the colour of the text (`fg`) turns green. Instead, when `dothis(i)` is called, it changes the colour of the last button generated to green. This is not what I want. 
To summarise, when I click button3, I want to see this:

[image]

But instead, I see this (the last generated button is modified, not the one I want):

[image]

How can I work around this, while still keeping the buttons generated in a loop?
Note: The buttons must also be modifiable after changing the colour e.g. Once changed to green, it can be turned back to red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the correct `lambda` expression, but the parameter you passed isn't related to the buttons you created. You should pass the `Button` widget as a parameter instead:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def dothis(button):
    button.config(fg='green')

for i in range(5):
    button = Button(root, width=30, text="button{}".format(i))
    button.config(fg='red', command=lambda i=button: dothis(i))
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

To achieve toggling between red and green, you can use ternary operator:

```
def dothis(button):
    button.config(fg='green' if button["foreground"]=="red" else "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on all buttons except the last one being anonymous, and using `command` instead of binding events, you can use partials:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

root = Tk()

button_callbacks = {}

def on_click(button):
    button.config(fg="green")

for i in range(5):    
    button = Button(root, width=30, text=f"button{i}", fg="red")
    callback_name = f"on_click_{i}"
    button_callbacks.update({callback_name: partial(on_click, button=button)})

    button.config(command=button_callbacks[callback_name])
    button.pack()
```

Using event binding would be a bit more straight-forward, but the behavior is not exactly the same as triggering a callback using `command`. Here's what that might look like:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def on_click(event):
    button = event.widget
    button.config(fg="green")

for i in range(5):    
    button = Button(root, width=30, text=f"button{i}", fg="red")
    button.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
    button.pack()
```